# How to add new SKSprideNodes off the screen and sync their animation with existing objects?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I am trying to animate multiple `SKSpriteNode`'s of the same type using single `SKAction`.

What I would like to do, is to display four `SKSpriteNode`'s of the same type on the screen. 
Then animate them all when the button is pressed and move them to the left. 
As soon as the first `SKSpriteNode` would leave the screen I want to add another `SKSpriteNode` off the screen position on the right side and add him to this `SKAction` loop.

Image below shows in detail what I am after.

[image]

So far I was able to display four `SKSpriteNode`'s of the same type on the screen and add them to the array.

```
    var squareBox = SKSpriteNode()

    func addSquares(size:CGSize){

    for var i = 0; i < 4; i++ {

        // Create a new sprite node from an image
        squareBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "noBox")

        // Square pysics settings
        squareBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.squareBox.frame.size)
        squareBox.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        squareBox.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = squareBoxCategory
        squareBox.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = leftEdgeCategory | edgeCategory

        // SquareBox positioning on X
        var xPos = size.width/5 + squareBox.size.height/2
        var xPosInt = Int(xPos) * (i + 1)
        xPos = CGFloat(xPosInt)
        var yPos = size.height/2 + (squareBox.size.height/2)

        squareBox.position = CGPointMake(xPos - squareBox.size.height/2, yPos)

        self.addChild(squareBox)
        squareArray.append(squareBox)

    }

}
```

I am not sure if that is correct way to animate four `SKSpriteNode`'s of the same type, but when the button is pressed they all seem to move to the left as desired.

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.button {

            let move = SKAction.moveByX(-size.width/5 - squareBox.size.height/2, y: 0, duration: 1)

            print("button clicked!")

            for box in squareArray {
                box.runAction(move)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created an invisible 1px line on the left edge of the screen to define when the first `SKSpriteNode` leaves the screen.

```
    func addLeftEdge(size:CGSize){

    let leftEdge = SKNode()
    leftEdge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointMake(1, 1), toPoint: CGPointMake(1, size.height))
    leftEdge.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = leftEdgeCategory

    self.addChild(leftEdge)
}
```

The problem with this approach is that `SKSpriteNode`'s in the array when I animate them don't respond on `didBeginContact` when they touch the 1px line.

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    println("contact!")

}
```

In the end I want to be able to apply the `Force` to all `SKSpriteNode`'s on the screen for a few seconds to move them to the left and descend the force speed over the time until they all stop. My idea was to create four objects of the same type and add them to the screen + add them to the array `var squareArray = [SKSpriteNode]()`. 
Then when the first `SKSpriteNode` leaves the screen I would remove it from array and add it again at the end and position it off the screen on the right so it will be moved in seamless animation.

I have a feeling that my entire approach is wrong.

Please advise what is the best approach to animate multiple `SKSpriteNode`'s to achieve my goal as described above. Am I on the right track ?

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect contact, one of the SKSpriteNodes must have `physicsBody.Dynamic= YES;`

Since you want neither to be dynamic, there is a quick fix I have found:

```
leftEdge.physicsBody.Dynamic=YES; //This allows it to enter onContact
leftEdge.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=0; //Disables edge from being moved by collision
leftEdge.physicsBody.AffectedByGravity=NO; //Prevents any in game gravity from moving the edge
```

This allows you have an edge that is dynamic and can trigger onContact yet the edge will still act as if it is not dynamic.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by creating category bitmasks for each object (line,square,frame edge) and setup collisionBitMasks accordingly. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: No Problem.  The rules I listed will still apply.  You didn't include your bitmasks in your code so I assumed they were correct.  Glad you found your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is always good to know there is another option to do the same. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution isn't very clean and requires a lot more code than what is necessary to get this effect. In the update() function since there are only 4 or 5 boxes why don't you simply loop through the objects and check if any of their `frame`'s `minX`'s are less than 0 and if they are reset them to the starting point which I'm assuming is `(view.frame.width + box.size.width)` because that's completely offscreen. That way there's no array manipulation in that you don't have to remove and append objects to the array. Also you don't need to attach a physicsBody where none is required. And you don't need the leftEdge